# limit_req on nginx not working

Tags: nginx, ddos

Iam using Ubuntu server 14.04 with apache + nginx proxy over it.
I tried to set up limit_req in 
/etc/nginx-sp/nginx-sp.conf

as this:

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:1m rate=10r/s;
    limit_req zone=one burst=50 nodelay;
.....
```

When I did this test, nothing happened:

```
ab -c 1000 -n 1000000 http://example.com
```

There are not logs at all in /var/log/nginx-sp
about limit_req

It seems that limit_req is not applied or my simulated DDoS attack is not good enough.

My cloudflare is switched off.

Comment: The documentation at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html implies limit_req goes into `server { location { } }` context. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, you are right it must be in `server { }`. I found one more mistake - my filter watched the wrong log file, my VPS use vhost, so it was not the standard log place. Now it is working and I feel save, may be :D